# Running function in for-loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop

New to R here and trying to place a function in a for loop. The function works and the for loop worked when I had another function in it, but when I put them together I am getting the error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" when I didn't need one before. The function I have is :

```
roll <- function(){

die<- 1:20 # 20 sided die

dice <- sample(die, 2, replace=TRUE) # Roll the die twice

sum(dice) # Add results

}
```

and I am trying to get it to run 100+ times while putting the output in a matrix. Maybe I am just not quite grasping the problem with the for loop but I have it as such:

```
for(i in 1:nrolls) { #nrolls=100

roll <- sample(die)

if(roll[i] >= 25) {

G_than <- 1

} else{

L_than <- 1

}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what will the output list look like?

Comment: Hoping to put the output list in 2 columns, one for a combined sum value >=25 and one for <25.

Comment: Can you explain what the for loop is trying to do? What is G_than and L_than for?

Comment: Trying to get the for loop to run the function 100 times and put the outcomes in a data frame of the summed values and whether they are >=25 or <25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loop aren't what you should use in that case.

Simply use sapply if you want to get the result in a vector like this:

```
roll <- function(x){
    die<- 1:20 # 20 sided die
    dice <- sample(die, 2, replace=TRUE) # Roll the die twice
    sum(dice) # Add results   
}
sapply(c(1:100), roll)
```

Note that sapply will send the argument to the function, so you need to change roll to get that input (and do nothing with it)